# How do I represent a complex number in ada?

Tags: ada, complex-numbers

Im trying to figure out how to represent a complex number in the ada programming language. Through research I figured  out about the with Ada.Numerics.Complex_Types package and looking at the package I dont see how the imaginary number 'i' is represented. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can represent 2+6i as (2.0, 6.0).

```
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Complex_Types;

procedure Cplx is

  type My_Real is digits 15;  --  Double precision

  package RC is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Complex_Types (My_Real);
  use RC;

  c: Complex;

begin
  c.Re := 2.0;
  c.Im := 6.0;
  --  More compact:
  c := (Re => 2.0, Im => 6.0);
  --  Even more compact:
  c := (2.0, 6.0);
end;
```

Comment: what is:
Ada.Numerics.Generic_Complex_Types (My_Real)?

Comment: Ada.Numerics.Generic_Complex_Types is a generic unit which is here instantiated with the type My_Real, a real type with 15 digits as relative precision.

Answer (score 2):

Ada complex types are explained in Appendix G.1.1 of the Ada Reference Manual.[Ada Reference Manual Appendix G.1.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-G-1-1.html)

Comment: yes I have read the appendix but I need clarification on a few things on there if that is fine with you

Comment: I see that there a data type IMAGINARY. Is that supposed to represent 'i'?

Comment: The package definition includes the following:


private
   type Imaginary is new Real'Base;
   i : constant Imaginary := 1.0;
   j : constant Imaginary := 1.0;
end Ada.Numerics.Generic_Complex_Types;


Imaginary is represented as a Real type.

Comment: so say if i wanted to represent (2+6i). would I do:
A: complex;
a.re:=2;
a.im:=6;

Comment: I suggest you use the function "function Compose_From_Cartesian (Re, Im : Real'Base) return Complex;"  This function will create a complex number as you propose.